# Specifying horizontal spacing for section title from the margin instead of after numbering

Tags: sectioning, titles, documentclass-writing

I am modifying the available class file for my requirement using renewcommand in the preamble.

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{0mm}%spacing before numbering
                               {-6pt \@plus 0pt \@minus 0pt}%
                               {12pt \@plus 0pt}%
                               {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{1.9cm}%\z@
                               {6pt \@plus 0pt \@minus 0pt}%
                               {12pt \@plus 0pt}%
                                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
                               {6pt \@plus 0pt \@minus 0pt}%
                               {12pt \@plus 0pt}%
                                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

 \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace*{0.64cm}}%spacing after numbering
```

The title spacing is specified after the numbering but, I want to specify it from the margin just like the hanging indent from MS Word. Is there any way?

And also, Is there any way to specify separate spacing for section, subsection and subsubsection?

Thank you

Happy new year

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The easiest is to do that with package `titlesec`.

Comment: Hey Bernard, I am familiar with the titlesec package. Can you please give me a hint how can I give spacing for the section title as my requirement?

Comment: If I've well understood what you want, you could for instance put the numbering in a box of a specified width equal to the distance from the margin that you want for your title.

Comment: Ah interesting, I will look into it. Thanks a lot.